# Reversing a Stack without using Java API

Tags: java, generics, recursion, linked-list, stack

i want to implement a reverse method that reverses a Stack. I think the solution is recursion. I tried my best, but it doesn't work. Can somebody tell me where my mistake is?

```
public class Stack<E> {

    private final E value;
    private final Stack<E> next;

    private Stack(E value, Stack<E> next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public static <E> Stack<E> create() {
        return null;
    }
    public static <E> Stack<E> push(Stack<E> a, E e) {
        Stack<E> erg = new Stack<E>(e,a);
        return erg;
    }

    public static <E> Stack<E> pop(Stack<E> a) { //pop(push(s,e) = s
        if (a == null) {
            return Stack.<E>create();
        }
        else if (a.value == null){
            return Stack.<E>create();
        }
        else {
            return a.next;
        }
    }
    public static <E> E top(Stack<E> a) {
        if (a == null) {
            return null;
        }
        else if (a.value == null){
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return a.value;
        }
    }
    public static <E> boolean isEmpty(Stack<E> a) {
        if (a == null) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (a.value == null) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static <E> Stack<E> reverse(Stack<E> s) {
        Stack<E> top = Stack.<E>pop(s);
        if (Stack.<E>isEmpty(s)) {
            return top;
        } else {
            Stack<E> bottom = reverse(s);
            Stack.<E>push(top, null);
            return bottom;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not allowed to use classes of th Java API; i'm not allowed to add more classes or methods or attributes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use another stack to reverse the stack.

```
public static <E> Stack<E> reverse(Stack<E> s) {
    Stack<E> reversedStack = new Stack<E>(null, null);
    while(!Stack.<E>isEmpty(s) {
        Stack.<E>push(reversedStack, s.value);
        s = Stack.<E>pop(s));
    }
    return reversedStack;
}
```

Comment: I get this:TestTimedOutException: test timed out after 555 milliseconds

Comment: Yes, but i implemented it like this. `public static <E> Stack<E> reverse(Stack<E> s) {
        Stack<E> reversedStack = new Stack<E>(null, null);
        while(!Stack.<E>isEmpty(s)) {
            reversedStack.<E>push(Stack.<E>pop(s), null);
        }
        return reversedStack;
    }`

Comment: what have you used this time?

Comment: Your Code. `public static <E> Stack<E> reverse(Stack<E> s) {
        Stack<E> reversedStack = new Stack<E>(null, null);
        while(!Stack.<E>isEmpty(s)) {
            Stack.<E>push(reversedStack, s.value);
            s = Stack.<E>pop(s);
        }
        return reversedStack;
    }`

Comment: I dont throws an exception now. But i get null

Comment: please try to add some values in the stack and after try to reverse it. Might be you are trying to reverse empty stack.

Comment: Based on the OP `push` implementation this line `Stack.<E>push(reversedStack, s.value);` needs to be `reversedStack = Stack.<E>push(reversedStack, s.value);`;  otherwise the push has no effect.

Comment: okay, then you get the idea. Update code accordingly.

Comment: There is one more thing. A test case returns "Stack.push(null, "JohnDoe") => pop failed." Is there something wrong with my pop() or push() method?

Comment: Stack.push is failed because you are pushing elements in null stack.

Comment: it will not work, Stack.push(null, "JohnDoe") because there is no stack. Java doesn't know in which stack you are pushing the elements.

Comment: And how can i fix this?

Comment: Pass one stack name, i.e Stack<E> newStack = new Stack<E>(null, null);
Stack.push(newStack, "JohnDoe")  something like this.

Comment: The mistake is in the pop method. There is a test case that checks, if it returns null. If so, the test case fails. So when i pop this: pop(push, "JohnDoe") i shouldnt return null

Comment: Sorry i cant upvote, because i need 15 reputations

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.  I'm using the Stack that's part of the API but as long as a stack has push and pop, any implementation should work.

- create a new stack in the reverse method.
- and as you pop one value from the original stack, push it on to the new stack.
- return the new stack

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    stack.push(i);
}

System.out.println(stack);
stack = reverse(stack);
System.out.println(stack);
    
    
public static <T> Stack<T> reverse(Stack<T> stack) {
    Stack<T> reversed = new Stack<>();
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        reversed.push(stack.pop());
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: There is another mistake shows up in pop. When i run this: Stack.push(null, "JohnDoe") it returns null, but it shouldnt. How can i solve this?

Comment: Why are you passing stack to push or pop?  Whether you are using a linked list or an array or list, you should not have to pass anything other than the arguments you are trying to push or pop.

Comment: Forgetting about reversing for a moment, does your stack work as intended and meets the requirements of the source of the training exercise?